How I detect which plugin is modifying my file on save?
I'm modifying a file on vim, but on save all the file get minified, there is clearly a misconfigured plugin, but there are no messages and I found no clue of which one is doing that.
Is there any easier or faster way than disable the plugins one by one?
The approaches I'm thinking (but I don't know how to do) are:

Getting a list of plugins that registered autocomands on the BufWrite event.
Adding some "verbose" setting to be able to catch what is happening under the hood.
Getting some logs of the save process.


For the first, try :au BufWrite and :au BufWriteCmd (sometimes it might be an external command), also :au BufWritePost

With the verbose option or -V you can write logs to a file

Also, try disabling plugins and adding them back in one at a time?

The specific issue I had was with the ALE plugin, I've disabled it using let g:ale_enabled=0, but that was not disabling the auto-fix (ALEFixer).
More in general, I want to summarize what was given as comments:

Getting a list of plugins that registered autocomands on the BufWrite event:
:au BufWrite
:au BufWritePost
:au BufWritePre
:au BufWriteCmd


Adding some "verbose" setting to be able to catch what is happening under the hood:
:set verbose=10
; but with lots of plugins make the application unusable


Getting some logs of the save process.
# start vim in verbose mode on level 10 (default)
# writing the logs to the file vim.log
vim -V10vim.log



